# Embedded linux printer using cups raster driver

Tags: python, linux, printing, raster, cups

I'm busy with a project to make a custom printer. basically a RPi/beaglebone connected to a gantry with stepper motors and a print-head.

I'm working on getting this setup to print an image from memory (with python), but I want to be able to print essentially any format from any application.

At this point I think the easiest way would be to setup CUPS on RPi to appear as a network printer over Wi-Fi. I've seen a few tutorials showing how to do this with a regular USB printer.

So I'd like to know how to write a custom CUPS raster driver that just takes the file and saves it as a raster image in memory at a specific dpi.

Otherwise, I'd like to know if there is an easier way to do this. It seems one should be able to simply query CUPS for a raster version of any job in the queue, not so?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask